# Fastest Way to Transfer a text file between 2 machines

Tags: networking, bluetooth, samba, file-sharing

I am currently trying to share 2 txt files between a Mac running Ventura and Ubuntu. Both files are about 560 bytes but the transfer has to be as fast as possible as my program writes/updates the files 60 times a second and this file has to be read on the other machine at the same time and vice versa.

I am currently using the file sharing option in Mac's system settings which uses smb. This currently creates a few seconds of lag. There also is an option called Bluetooth sharing on the Mac side but I'm unsure if this will make the transfer speed any faster.

Comment: This depends on hardware not on software. Next: from just these few lines ... your software is another problem. You open the file from the other machine in your software.That way there are no timing issues.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "open the file from the other machine in your software". To clarify what I'm trying to do, the 2 machines are running the same program simultaneously and the webcam data (the txt file) is sent to the other computer while the webcam data from the other computer is getting received. I'm trying to do this real time but even without the post processing of these data, there seems to be a latency issue. I do not know if my internet speed is causing that, but if there's another protocol that could increase the transfer speed, that's what I'm looking for.